# Are threads copied when calling fork?

Tags: c, multithreading, unix, process, fork

If I have a program running with threads and call `fork()` on a unix-based system, are the threads copied? I know that the virtual memory for the current process is copied 1:1 to the new process spawned. I know that threads have their own stack in the virtual memory of a process. Thus, at least the stack of threads should be copied too. However, I do not know if there is anything more to threads that does not reside in virtual memory and is thus NOT copied over. If there is not, do the two processes share the threads or are they independent copies?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

#### No.

Threads are not copied on `fork()`. POSIX specification says (emphasize is mine):

> fork - create a new process
>
> **A process shall be created with a single thread**. If a multi-threaded process calls fork(), the new process shall contain a replica of the calling thread and its entire address space, possibly including the states of mutexes and other resources. Consequently, to avoid errors, the child process may only execute async-signal-safe operations until such time as one of the exec functions is called.

To circumvent this problem, there exists a `pthread_atfork()` function to help.

Answer (score 8):

[man fork](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html):

> The child process is created with a single thread—the one that called fork(). The entire virtual address space of the parent is replicated in the child, including the states of mutexes, condition variables, and other pthreads objects; the use of pthread_atfork(3) may be helpful for dealing with problems that this can cause.

Comment: But that seems weird: Why would stack for the threads in the process calling fork be copied if the actual threads(which I do not know contain storage somewhere else than virtual memory) are not?

Comment: Well the *why* of it is a different question altogether. I don't know the original design decisions that led to that implementation. If you are interested you should ask that as a seperate question.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès "but stack of other threads are not copied" I do not think I said that. I wondered why the stacks of threads located in the virtual memory is copied over to the new process(since the virtual memory is copied) if the actual executing threads - the ones that initiate context switching and all that - is not. Seems like waste of memory then :/

Comment: @dip I think what is referred by virtual memory is bss+heap, while can I admit this is not clear. But even if it is copied, you should know that thing are "virtually" copied (by copy-on-write technic).

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès In unix systems, there is a struct representing the virtual memory for a process. That is the one copied. Not just the heap and bss

Comment: you get the entire memory space - and therefore the stacks of all threads.  you need that because there is no limitation on where the pointers living in the stack (or static memory) accessible to the remaining thread are pointing - they could very well be pointing to data that lived in some thread's stack in the original process

Comment: @Dip The term "stack for the threads in the process" is a misleading term. Stacks are process resources and while there is one stack for each thread in the process, the stacks are fully shared and it is perfectly normal for threads to access objects on any of those stacks.

Comment: @Dip What if the object that happened to be executing at that moment also happened to be allocated on the stack of another thread in the process? That's perfectly normal and routine. Stacks, and objects created on them, are fully shared among threads in a process just like the heap is. For example, the initial thread might create a control object on the stack executing `main` that is used by many threads through the life of the process. That it happens to be on the stack the initial thread executes on doesn't change the fact that objects on it, like all objects, are shared.

Answer (score 4):

From The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 7, 2018 edition's [fork](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html):

> A process shall be created with a single thread. If a multi-threaded process calls *fork()*, the new process shall contain a replica of the calling thread and its entire address space, possibly including the states of mutexes and other resources. Consequently, to avoid errors, the child process may only execute async-signal-safe operations until such time as one of the [*exec*](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html) functions is called.
>
> When the application calls *fork()* from a signal handler and any of the fork handlers registered by [*pthread_atfork()*](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_atfork.html) calls a function that is not async-signal-safe, the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score -3):

Originally, "fork" was achieved by writing the task to disk and then, rather than reading in a different thread (which would be done if swapping the task with a different one), modifying the task ID of the image still in memory and continuing with its execution (as the new task).  This was a very simple modification to the basic task switching mechanism, where only one task would occupy RAM memory at a time.

Of course, as memory management got more elaborate this scheme was modified to suit the new environment.

Comment: Curious why this was down-voted.  This is the way Unix did it.

Comment: This is interesting insight, but where does it mention threads? Doesn't look like an answer to me.